# Flutter Xcode 12 archive build fails with Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAPIClient

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, simulator

[image]Flutter version 1.22.2
Xcode 12.1

the app builds fine in the simulator but trying to generate an archive for App Store fails with: building for iOS-armv7 but attempting to link with file built for iOS-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_STPAPIClient", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in TPSStripeManager.o

Comment: Hi, have you solved it?

Answer (score 6):

I have deployment target to 11.0.

XCode->Pods->stripe_payment->Build Setting. Change the iOS Deployment Target to 11.0. Without knowing exact reason for the problem however this worked for me.

I have attached the xcode ss.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Xcode Pods:[Adding armv7 to excluded architectures solved the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plYIC.png)

This works for me.